# React native EXPO installation (npm start)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bundler

I created my app in react native using Expo but when i run the `npm start` command its showing me this:

```
running metro bundler on port 8081
```

and then

```
loading dependency graph, done
```

and never end. what to do?

Here is the [complete console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI3be.png).

Comment: Are you using Expo ? Can you provide the console output ?

Comment: Yes i am using Expo and i have provided the output. see question

Comment: Did you execute the react-native run-android in another terminal?

Comment: Yes, i executed this command before but nothing happened.

Comment: Assuming you installed [expo-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-cli) globally and followed the expo [getting started](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/), you can start your expo application with the following command : `expo start` in your project directory.

You don't need to start local-cli via node_modules or whatever you tried in your screenshot :)

Comment: Just a few questions, are you in linux or Mac or windows? Are you using Expo or you are doing a simple react native project.

Comment: Is should say that please frist do `yarn start` or `npm i` in a path of your project in a terminal.
Then in another terminal you have to execute `react-native run-android` or `react native-run-ios`.

Comment: This is the react native packager or metro bundler. It packages your JS code for you. You keep that open while developing apps and the native app will read JS code from the packager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you have a bundler like the one that you have used then it would suggest that you have used `react-native init` to create you application, instead of expo.

Expo bunders look like this: 
[image: expo bundler image]

If you have created a `react-native init` and as it suggests in your screenshot that you are building the app on a **Windows machine**, that means you will be developing on Android.

The instructions for using Android and running react-native are quite long and complicated, they can be found here. For the sake of brevity I am not going to repeat them here  asyou can just follow this link. Make sure to choose **Building Projects with Native Code** -> **Development OS: Windows** -> **Target OS: Android** to find the instructions that are pertinent to your situation. 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

If you are planning on developing on an emulator then you will need to make sure that you have one installed (the link above has all the info that you need). Also you need to make sure that you launch your emulator before running `react-native run-android` if you do that then it should load on to the emulator and you should be able to see what you are developing on.

If you want to run on your own Android device then you should follow the instructions on this page https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device (again choosing the options for your situation).

#### Expo

If this feels like too much effort, you can always try Expo. It doesn't require you to be able to deal with native code. And depending on your use case can be a better option than creating a project with `react-native init`, plus you can always eject from the expo project and turn it in to a full fledged react-native app.

You install the expo-cli with

`npm install -g expo-cli`

Then download the expo app from the App Store or the Google Play Store (depending on the mobile that you are using).

Then you can use

`expo init`

to create your application

Check out the expo documentation for more information https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/workflow/up-and-running

Comment: it really helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Nice question, First of all, I totally understand what's exactly your problem is, let me give you a solution in a very appropriate way.

Basically, there is two way to install and setup React Native Project on your mac and windows machines

**1st React Native (native) Method: (That's basically you're using right know**

*Note: If you're using Apple product -  Like MacBook then you can do IOS and Android both platform by using this method, if you're using Windows or Linux you can only do this part for Android platforms*

In this method, we have to follow these simple steps

1. Download Nodejs from Offical website [link here](https://nodejs.org/en/)
2. Installing the React Native Cli

   npm install -g react-native-cli

If you get an error like Cannot find module 'npmlog', try installing npm directly: curl -0 -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh.
(Only for mac)

3. Install the Xcode from Appstore (Only for Mac user/macos users)
   otherwise

download and install the Android Studio (Stable version) from the official website of Android studio

4. Setup Xcode (Simulator) or Setup Android Studio for Android devices use (emulator)
   by learn and guide from this [link here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)

Note: Basically in your scenario, I'm pretty sure you didn't set up your emulator for android and simulator for IOS that's why you didn't see anything after
**2nd React Native with Expo Method:** that's you're not using a loading dependency graph

Use

**For Android**

react-native run-android

**For IOS**

react-native run-ios

**2nd React Native without Expo (that's not your case):**

In this method, we have to follow these simple steps

1. Download Nodejs from Offical website [link here](https://nodejs.org/en/)
2. installing expo cli

   npm install -g expo-cli

   expo init yourprojectname

   cd yourprojectname

   npm start

**Note: Simulators and emulators way same for both**